# Django form DateTimeField : select a valid date and a valid time

Tags: django, forms

I have a form with datetimefield format :

```
class DateTimeInput(forms.DateTimeInput):
    input_type = "datetime-local"



class myform(forms.ModelForm):
    myfield= forms.DateTimeField(input_formats = ["%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"], 
             widget=DateTimeInput(attrs={ 'class':'form-control'}))
```

but I have still the error "select a valid date and a valid time".
My input looks like 14/02/2021 15:59

Answer (score 0):

```
myfield= forms.DateTimeField(
    input_formats = ['%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'],
    widget = forms.DateTimeInput(
        attrs={
            'type': 'datetime-local',
            'class': 'form-control'},
        format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.